# Given a command - use regex to call methods in java/groovy

Tags: java, regex, groovy, command

For the input command string I want to use regex to match and execute appropriate method.

For e.g.
1. User input is "phone 323244332"

> Then I want to call a method which will take phone number as argument and saves it to DB

Similarly there will be about ~100 commands and corresponding method to call.

How can we implement the same in Java or Groovy? I can port the solution to other language as needed. Is there any known design patterns or solutions for the same?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At its most basic level, you could do this in Groovy:

```
def phone( String number ) {
    println "phone called with $number"
}

String userCommand = 'phone 323244332'

userCommand.split().with {
   "${head()}"( *tail() )
}
```

But if you have multiple commands or commands per user request AND your commands are going to be in a style parseable by groovy (ie: parameters separated by commas), then you may consider writing a groovy dsl... However, I suspect you're going to struggle with a full on DSL, as I guess numbers could be `00441784984456`, which without double quotes will get interpreted as an invalid octal number (and so will fail)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need a regexp. You can simply split on whitespace and then use [reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/) to find a corresponding method on a class (e.g. `phone(String num)`) and execute that.

e.g. in pseudo-code:

```
String[] args = input.split(" ");
Method[] allMethods = declaringClass.getDeclaredMethods();
for (Method m : allMethods) {
    if (m.getName().equals(args[0])) {
       // call it here...
       m.invoke(....);
    }
}
```

Note that this is platform-specific, so the above would work on the JVM, but a different approach would be required for (say) Perl.

Comment: Its a simple example I gave, in reality there could be multiple possibilities for the same command. Is there any pattern to solve this problem?

Comment: The reflection API allows you to find methods on an object and identify their arg types etc. I think you'll have to perform some sort of pattern match based on your inputs.

Comment: Exactly - I believe i need to pattern match based on inputs. Do you know any example by change? I am trying to find one by googling...

Comment: @18bytes: Note the [drawback of reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/): `Because reflection involves types that are dynamically resolved, certain Java virtual machine optimizations can not be performed. Consequently, reflective operations have slower performance than their non-reflective counterparts, and should be avoided in sections of code which are called frequently in performance-sensitive applications.`

Answer (score 0):

you can create static methods with the valid arguments and then automatically static import the methods on a groovy sheel